# Multiple defintion error, Linker error

Tags: arduino-uno, c, avr-toolchain

Trying to create an elf file for two sets of files in different folders.

```
LIDARBOT.h
-----------
#ifndef LIDARBOT_H_
#define LIDARBOT_H_

#include <avr/io.h>
#include "drivers/motors.h"

#endif

LIDARBOT.C
----------
#include "LIDARBOT.h"
int main(){
  pwmtimersetup();
    while (1) {
    }
}

motors.h
--------
#ifndef MOTORS_H_
#define MOTORS_H_

#include <avr/io.h>

void pwmtimersetup(void);

#endif

motors.c
--------
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "motors.h"

void pwmtimersetup(void){
  // Timer pre-scalar for ~490 Hz is 8
  TCCR0B &= ~((1<<CS02)||(1<<CS00));
  TCCR0B |=  (1<<CS01);
  // Set Compare Output Mode to Toggle PWM
  TCCR0A &= ~(1<<COM0A1);
  TCCR0A |=  (1<<COM0A0);
  // Waveform Generation Mode: WGM02 = 1, WGM01 = 1, WGM00 = 1
  TCCR0B |= (1<<WGM02);
  TCCR0A |= (1<<WGM01)||(1<<WGM00);
  OCR0A = 125;
  DDRD |= (1<<DDD4)||(1<<DDD2);
  PORTD |= (1<<PORTD4);
  PORTD &= (1<<PORTD2);
}
```

I can make a consolidated object file but not an elf file to load onto my board. Output below:

```
avr-gcc -g -Os -Wall -Werror -Wextra  -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL -Wa,-ahlmns=LIDARBOT.lst -o objects/LIDARBOT.o \
source/LIDARBOT.c \
source/drivers/motors.c \
-I/home/manu/C/Arduino/LIDARBOT/libraries/

avr-gcc -g -Os -Wall -Werror -Wextra -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL -o elf/LIDARBOT.elf objects/LIDARBOT.o
objects/LIDARBOT.o: In function `__vector_22':
(.text+0x7c): multiple definition of `__bad_interrupt'
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
objects/LIDARBOT.o: In function `__vectors':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vectors'
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o:(.vectors+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:191: elf] Error 1
```

I am kind of lost. What could be my mistake here? If I see an error like this how do i start to debug?

Comment: I realized that i did not need to add #include <avr/io.h> in the motors.c file. I removed that and tried it again. Same error.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by the first `avr-gcc` command line? In that command line I see multiple source files, only one output file and no `-c`? This looks like a full compile and link, but saving the resultant elf as an `.o` file. But why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the -c flag to your first command. That means you have first compiled your program into a full elf file. Then you try to link that elf file with the standard startup libraries again (it already contains them) into another new elf file.

And so you get duplicate entries in it.

Add -c to your first command, which means "compile only, don't link" to create object files not an elf file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your input, AnT and Majenko. I realized my issue which was trying to link a .o file into another one. So I corrected my make file by individually compiling but not linking the source files with the -c option. I then made my final elf file using the unlinked .o files.